# How do I use remote Powershell commands in managed code?

Tags: c#, powershell, dynamic, exchange-server-2010, powershell-remoting

[The linked article describes how to use Exchange Powershell with C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332449%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx), but it is cumbersome and apparently outdated.

What is the correct or modern way to call remote powershell commands in managed code?

The following just feels overly verbose and archaic.

```
Runspace myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
myRunSpace.Open();
Pipeline pipeLine = myRunSpace.CreatePipeline();
Command getCommand = new Command("Get-Command");
pipeLine.Commands.Add(getCommand);
Command getMember = new Command("Get-Member");
pipeLine.Commands.Add(getMember);
Collection<PSObject> commandResults = pipeLine.Invoke();
```

Comment: Have you seen this? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c.aspx it's PS v3 from April of this year.  Looks like you are right; the api has been simplified- you can simply `AddScript` and then `Invoke`